# Can every power series be representated as a taylor series?

Tags: calculus, power-series, taylor-expansion

Can every [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series) be represented as a [Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)?

More concrete: Given an arbitrary power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-x_0)^n$, is there always a $C^\infty$-function $f$ such that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n (x-x_0)^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{n}(x_0)}{n!} (x-x_0)^n$, i.e. for each sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ exists a $C^\infty$-function $f$ with $a_n = \frac{f^{n}(x_0)}{n!}$?

Comment: If the power series has radius of convergence $R>0$ then on $(x_0-R,x_0+R)$, $f(x) = \sum a_n (x-x_0)$ defines a $C^\infty$ function that has Taylor series (at $x_0$) equal to itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To further expand the comment of @James,

given an arbitrary sequence of numbers $a_n$ and fixed point $x_0$, there exists a $C^\infty_c(\Bbb R)$ function $\phi$ such that $\phi^{(n)}(x_0)=a_n$ (this fact is useful in the theory of distributions).